# how to subtract two query count in php mysql

Tags: mysql

MySQL Query 1 -

```
SELECT assets.name, models.model_number,
      COUNT(CASE when (month(DATE_ADD(purchase_date, INTERVAL 1461 DAY)) BETWEEN 2 AND 4) AND Year(DATE_ADD(purchase_date, INTERVAL 1461 DAY))<=year(curdate()) THEN 1 end)      
   as total_count FROM assets, models WHERE assets.model_id = models.id AND status_id=30 or status_id=1
```

MySQL Query2-

```
SELECT assets.name, models.model_number,
      COUNT(CASE when (month(DATE_ADD(purchase_date, INTERVAL 1461 DAY)) BETWEEN 2 AND 4) AND Year(DATE_ADD(purchase_date, INTERVAL 1461 DAY))<=year(curdate()) THEN 1 end)      
   as total_count FROM assets, models WHERE assets.model_id = models.id AND status_id=26 or status_id=1
```

Now i want to subtract query1 to query2.  Anyone  can help me here ?

First Query - Result

### Name     |       Model Number   |    Total_Count

### Windows Laptop          E7440              12

Second Query - Result

### Name    |         Model Number   |   Total_Count

### Windows Laptop        E7440                1

Now I want something like this….

### Name        |    Model Number  |Total_Count  |  Pending (Query1-Query2)

### Windows Laptop     E7440              12           11

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. I also failed to find any difference between the two queries you have provided. Please state clear your issue and your goal

Comment: The judicious placement of parentheses would probably help; at present it is highly unlikely that either query reflects your intention.

Comment: @jjd a different parameter in the where clause is the difference between the two queries

Comment: First query will give me the count of all assets which are four year old from the date of purchase and assets satus are 26 or 1.
Second query will give me the count of all assets which are four year old from the date of purchase and assets satus are 30 or 1.

I want to minus query one output with query2 output

Comment: You probably also want to see the query1result-query2result for the same asset and model, right?

Comment: @jjd Yes you are right

Comment: First Query - Result 

Name | Model Number | Total_Count 
Windows Laptop E7440 12 

Second Query - Result 

Name | Model Number | Total_Count 
Windows Laptop E7440 1 

Now I want something like this….
 
Name |  Model Number | Total_Count |Pending (Query1 -Query2)  
Windows Laptop E7440    12          11

Comment: Can anyone help me on this ?